# Trouble Adding Object To NSMutableArray in For Loop

Tags: objective-c

I'm having some trouble adding an object to an NSMutableArray in a for loop. When I try it, I get an error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
>   Blockquote

I've looked at other questions very similar to this and they are solved because the array was immutable or they were reading off NSUserDefaults, however I am doing neither of those things.

I download some JSON and parse it using NSJSONSelialization, and the idea is that I have an almost twitter-like stream of activity coming down from the top of the UITableView. Here's my code:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
if (isDownloadingFirstTime){
    isDownloadingFirstTime = NO;
    dataArray = [Methods parseJSONDataWithData:data];
    [mainTableView reloadData];
} else{
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
    NSArray *tempArray = [Methods parseJSONDataWithData:data];

    for (int num = 0; num < tempArray.count; num++){
        [dataArray addObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:num]];
        NSArray *indexPathArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
        [mainTableView beginUpdates];
        [mainTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [mainTableView endUpdates];
    }
}
data = [NSMutableData data];
}
```

I get the exception on the first line of the for loop, when I try to addObject:

I in no way am using NSUserDefaults in this class and I'm 100% sure that dataArray is an NSMutableArray.

Any help or advice is appreciated!

Comment: "mutating method sent to immutable object". Think about that for a minute.

Comment: Add `NSAssert( [dataArray isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]], @"Not mutable" )`.

Comment: does `dataArray = [[Methods parseJSONDataWithData:data] mutableCopy];` fix it?

Comment: @vikingosegundo That worked for me, thanks! If you would just make that an official answer I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dataArray` isn't a mutable array. You might did type the pointer as one, but that doesn't make the object itself mutable. The easiest would by to wit a mutable copy tho `dataArray`.

```
dataArray = [[Methods parseJSONDataWithData:data] mutableCopy];
```